# Configuring webpack for svelte with typescript

Tags: typescript, webpack, svelte

I started project and Im trying to use svelte + typescript and webpack. Problem I met is that webpack with https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-loader not catching typescript error. `.tsconfig` is proper for sure and VSC I use for development is able to highlight typescript errors but webpack builds without issues. This strange behaviour touches only `.svelte` files. Regular `.ts` are handled properly. Does anybody know how to force webpack to catch the ts errors in svelte files?

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately the [intended behavior](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess/blob/main/docs/preprocessing.md#typescript---limitations).

> Since v4, `svelte-preprocess` doesn't type-check your component, its only concern is to transpile it into valid JavaScript for the compiler. If you want to have your components type-checked, you can use [svelte-check](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/blob/master/packages/svelte-check/README.md).

You can probably just include that as a build step, its exit code should tell you whether errors occurred. Or use [machine readable output](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/blob/master/packages/svelte-check/README.md#machine-readable-output) and check for `FAILURE`.

Comment: thx H.B. ... anyways this sounds really bad. svelte-check is cli and I would have plugin so errors are catched during development. What is the solution then? Trust VSC highlighting this cant be true.

Comment: For development the [Svelte extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=svelte.svelte-vscode) should tell you about errors.

Comment: But this is VSC extension, i have it. But it is not acceptable solution. Highlight can be simple overlooked while buggy ts just shouldnt build right?

Comment: Well yes, but you can just call `svelte-check` before/during/after your regular build step to verify type correctness.